# DataTables fnSettings() method underfind

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, datatable

Have the following problem when resizing browser
Here's the code generates an error of the method, the method is not found or is not a function, but the method itself is present in the plugin...

```
this.fnSettings = function()
    {
        return _fnSettingsFromNode( this[_ext.iApiIndex] );
    };
```

line number 5911 in latest version plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/Almag13/xaLm2sjn/

why this error occurs and how to cure it

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your datatable as DataTable() (new version) , and not as dataTable() (old version).

```
 var oTable = $('#table-id').dataTable({
     scrollY: wrapperHeight,
     scrollX: true,
     scrollCollapse: true,
     paging: false
 });
```

Working example forked from yours (and corrected ) : http://jsfiddle.net/supersonique/4kw36uue/

Docs from datatable on new DataTable() syntax : https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10